# mapreduce tasks only run on namenode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have builded a Hadoop cluster on three machines; these are the characteristics:

- OS:Ubuntu14.04LTS
- Hadoop:2.6.0
- NameNode and ResourceManager IP: namenode/192.168.0.100
- DataNode also as the NodeManger IP: data1/192.168.0.101, data2/192.168.0.102

I have configed all xml files as official doc. When I execute the wordcount example program in eclipse, I wanna show the machine information, which is running the mapTask or reduceTask, so here is my code snippet.

```
//get localhost
InetAddress mLocalHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("Task on " + mLocalHost);
```

above the snippet was put into map and reduce function and runs it on hadoop. Nevertheless the console always show:

```
Task on namenode/192.168.0.100
```

From my perspective, these tasks should run on data1 or data2. Can you explain the puzzle? Whats wrong with my cluster?

Whats more?

the jobHistory(namenode:19888) records nothing.

and webAppProxy(namenode:8088) just show the active nodes:2, but nothing more infomation about job.

can you help me? really appreciated.

namenode's further info below,

jps command show:

12647 Jps

11426 SecondaryNameNode

11217 NameNode

11585 ResourceManager

12033 JobHistoryServe

Comment: I think you should print the complete log traces.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put that code,  Is it in your Driver class ? You need to have it in your mapper or reducer so that you can see which node is processing.

Instead of that you can have a look at resource manager web ui at `rmipaddress:8088` which will give you more details on which node is executing mappers and other logs.

Answer (score 0):

i have found whats wrong with my problem. "run on hadoop" in Eclipse just starts the job locally, so i should modify the MyHadoopXML.xml file which is under Eclipse plugins' sub-directory. Otherwise, i just develop and debug mapreduce job locally and export the project into a jar, then run the jar with command of "hadoop jar" in the cluster to verify whether the job is executed successfully.